# Objdump Address representation

Tags: objdump

I recently tried my hands on Objdump of a c object file . For each instruction there was an address associated with it. I tried searching the web for what this address represents and found out that the address was basically the address of the instruction . However my question is that while doing the objdump the program is not running so how can the address of the instruction be determined . Isn't the address of the instruction supposed to be the it's address when the program is loaded onto memory  ?

Comment: address is object file is basically offset which is used in conjunction with base address when application is actually loaded into memory

Comment: Is it possible to get the base address when the program in running ?